# How to Implement Slicing with rules and slice size limitation of large xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm receiving a large file holding data of different items:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
       <Property1>...</Property1>
       <Property2>...</Property2>
       <Property3>...</Property3>
        ...
    </Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
</Items>
```

and I need first to group items by distinct list of properties (which should be configurable without code change) then slice the groups to chunks and be able to implement GetNextChunk() method.
Any recommendations of specific ways to implement that?

Comment: Slicing? Do you mean streaming, i.e. reading data by chunks?

Comment: With slicing .. do you mean separating each `<Item></Item>` group?

Comment: For example: need to group all items that proprty1 has same values in groups of max size of 5 items...